# Как проверить существует ли сообщение в телеграм канале/группе, зная message_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота для модерации чата с использованием библиотеки aiogram. Тк данный бот будет работать в совокупности с другими админ-ботами, то перед модерацией триггерного сообщения требуется проверить существует ли оно, а не удалено уже другим ботом. В связи с тем, что в aiogram отсутствуют методы для прямой подобной проверки, решил попробовать такой способ:

```
async def message_exist(chat_id, message_id, bot):
    try:
        await bot.copy_message(chat_id=987, from_chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id) # в качестве chat_id рандомное заведомо неверное значение, которое переводит в except с ошибкой chat not found 
    except TelegramBadRequest as ex:
        if 'Telegram server says - Bad Request: message to copy not found' in str(ex):
            return True


@rt.message(F.text)
async def moderate(msg: Message, bot: Bot):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if not await message_exist(msg.chat.id, msg.message_id, bot):
            # далее требуемый код
```

И все казалось бы работает, но только в том случае, если в качестве message_id в функцию передать значение, значительно превышающее id последнего сообщения в чате. Например, последнее сообщение в чате имеет id=234. Если передать id=234567, то функция возвращает True, следовательно проверка срабатывает, как и требуется. Если же передать id=235, то True не возвращается. Аналогично работает и метод delete_message: если передаешь в него id сообщение, близкое к крайнему в чате.

Какие еще есть способы проверки сообщения на его наличие в чате без использования юзер ботов?